# How do I check the name of a parent directory?

Tags: javascript

I have a fake directory for my question:

```
main
  sub.js
```

Is there any way for me to figure out the name of the parent directory of sub.js inside of sub.js?

Eg:

```
/* This will be run in sub.js */ getParent() // Returns "main"
```

Comment: Is this on the server or the client?

Comment: Client, at least I think. I'm running the javascript file on my machine.

Comment: Is it running in the browser or on the command line?

Comment: Oh. Its running on the browser.

Comment: In the browser? Like as a web app? What does the browser care about the directory on the server?

Comment: Well, all of my HTML projects are required to link to a certain file. I need to  make this file have some configuration settings so that it will work on different devices. I have these files on my machine, and there is no server involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the location object like so:

```
var lastSlash = location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/');
var directoryName = location.pathname.substr(1,lastSlash);
```

Comment: So this needs an HTML file? I'll test it out, it looks like this will work.

Comment: Perfection! Thanks for this, I've been spending lots of time on this confusing problem.